# How to auto-select in a combo box, populate a textbox, and submit a button on a javascript-based website using VB.NET and WebView?

Tags: vb.net, webview

Using VB.NET, Visual Basic, and the WebView, I am trying to figure out how to automate the selection of a combo box item, how to populate a textbox, and then how to click on a submit button. The website I am trying to automate uses javascript, and I haven't found a good example on how this works, using WebView. So far I can only navigate to the various web pages, and can pull the innerHTML into a string.

The combo box I wish to auto-select ("Directory Number") is here:

```
<select onchange="getUtilityListValues(this, &quot;PhoneFindListForm&quot;, updateUtilityList); onSearchFieldChange(0)" size="1" id="searchField0" name="searchField0">
<option value="device.name">Device Name</option>
<option value="device.description">Description</option>
**<option value="numplan.dnorpattern">Directory Number</option>**
<option value="numplanuri.uri">Directory URI</option>
<option value="altnumber.dnderived">Alternate Number</option>
<option value="callingsearchspace.name">Calling Search Space</option>
<option value="devicepool.name">Device Pool</option>
<option value="TypeProduct.name">Device Type</option>
<option value="pickupgroup.name">Call Pickup Group</option>
<option value="TypeCertificateStatus.name">LSC Status</option>
<option value="device.LSCValidUntil">LSC Expires</option>
<option value="device.LSCIssuerName">LSC Issued By </option>
<option value="device.LSCIssuerValidUntil">LSC Issuer Expires By</option>
<option value="device.authenticationString">Authentication String</option>
<option value="TypeDeviceProtocol.name">Device Protocol</option>
<option value="securityprofile.name">Security Profile</option>
<option value="commondeviceconfig.name">Common Device Configuration</option>
</select>
```

The next combo box I wish to auto-select ("ends with") is here:

```
<input id="searchLimVal0" value="" name="searchLimVal0" type="hidden">
<option value="beginsWith">begins with</option>
<option value="contains">contains</option>
**<option value="endsWith">ends with</option>**
<option value="isExactly">is exactly</option>
<option value="isEmpty">is empty</option>
<option value="isNotEmpty">is not empty</option>
</select>
```

The text box I wish to enter text ("2399") into is here:

```
<input id="searchString0" onkeypress="javascript:onEnterKey(event)" value="" name="searchString0" type="text">
```

And the "Find" button I wish to auto-click is here:

```
<input value="Find" class="cuesButton" name="findButton" onclick="javascript:onFindSubmit()" type="button">
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

I've tried this line for the text box, but nothing happens:

```
webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementByid('searchString0').value = '2399';")
```

Comment: Have a feeling you're not able to do exactly what you're attempting here without 3rd party tools.  Possibly something like HTMLAglity pack?

Comment: I have the webview code working well now. Not sure why the earlier attempts didn't work, but as an example, this code correctly sets a dropdown option: webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('searchField0').value = 'numplan.dnorpattern';")

Comment: This code correctly got the Find button to be clicked, using the class: webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('cuesButton')[0].click();")